# CsvHelper - Skip rows from csv file arbitrary rows

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I have a csv file like this

'some lines to skip : line 1 to 7'
Name,Family,Mobile
'line nine: should be skipped'
'line ten: should be skipped'
A,B,1
C,D,2

How Can I skip **first seven** lines and **third** line with **ShouldSkipRecord** by RowIndex?
I've searched a lote but I did not find any solutions.

This is my codes

```
var options = new TypeConverterOptions { Formats = new[] { "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" } };
using var reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Arash\Desktop\fault1.csv");
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
     ShouldSkipRecord = args =>
     {
        //some thing which show row index
     }
};
using var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config);
csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<FaultsModelMap>();
csv.Context.TypeConverterOptionsCache.AddOptions<DateTime>(options);
var records = csv.GetRecords<FaultsModel>();
```

Comment: Is there any structure to which row that indicates if there is any rows to skip? Is it always the first one?

Comment: dear @alapaah the first seven lines should be skipped, line 8 is header, lines 9,10  should skip then data is line 11 to the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear @JoshClose answered my question in the **[Github](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/2218)**, I share the solution with developers who will be faced with same issue.

```
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    ShouldSkipRecord = args =>
    {
        var rawRow = args.Row.Parser.RawRow;
        return rawRow < 8 || rawRow == 9 || rawRow == 10;
    }
};
```

Please don't forget that line indices starts from **1** not **0**